# Cannot .collect() in Apache Spark Java, OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm completely new to Spark (running on MacOS) and I've been trying to test out some .parquet files I have in my PC which are around 120mb in size, trying to run them locally with master set to `local[*]`.

Basically the pipeline of operations I currently have is the following one...

```
        dataset
            .where(...)
            .toJavaRDD()
            .sortBy(...) // Tried .collect() here. Current 'debug' point.
            .groupBy(...) // Tried .collect() here.
            .flatMapValues(...)
            .mapToPair(...) // Tried .collect() here.
            .reduceByKey(...); // Tried .collect() here.
```

The first thing I would like to ask, **how can I check the parquet file schema?** I've read out something that it's possible with Hive but haven't found anything. If you have any resources that can be useful to me it would be really appreaciated.

Secondly, as I don't really know all the parquet column names I must access in groupBy() and such, I'm just trying to collect everything in the first sortBy(), see what comes out and such (some minor testing in order to get started with Spark and how everything works). But as the question says I always get the given error. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't I .collect() after all?

I tried to print at some points but it seems that it goes to some logs as far as I've read and I don't really know if they are stored locally in the computer or how can I access them so I can see the output?

When it comes to the Spark configuration, it's the most basic one.

```
    final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .setAppName("test_app_name");

    final JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    // Get the singleton instance of SparkSession
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .config(jsc.getConf())
            .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read()
            .parquet(inputPath);
```

Comment: `dataset.printSchema` should give you the schema of your dataframe. `collect` will bring the entire content of your `dataset` to your driver's memory and I don't think `dataset.collect` is the right argument to part ot `sortBy` and `groupBy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply @philantrovert , first part of the problem solved! Just got the schema, perfect! Which would be the best approach to get just a little part of the data in order to preview it without that huge amount of data being loaded into memory?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with your dataframe, but you have sort and grouping methods for dataframe. So instead of converting it to RDD you can try achieving whatever you can with the dataframe API. Here are a bunch of functions : https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

Comment: Is there any substantial difference in performance when working directly with the dataframe API? @philantrovert

Comment: TBH, it depends on a lot of factors. I'll just say don't get caught up with premature performance turnings. Just try to follow a proper method to solve your problem. Start with reading the docs and you'll find a lots of Dos and Don'ts in there.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a collect action in spark is not good if your data is huge. Collect essentially brings all the data to the driver. This will cause memory outOf bound in the driver. Unless you are absolutely sure that the data you are collecting is pretty small.

To see the dataset/dataframe schema you need to do

```
 dataset.printSchema
```

To print a few rows of the dataset you can use the followings

```
 dataset.show(10) // number of rows you want to see
```

Or

```
 dataset.take(10).foreach(println) // takes 10 rows and print
```

If you want to see random rows for sampling you might use

```
 df.select("name").sample(.2, true).show(10)
```

Or

```
 df.select("name").sample(.2, true).take(10).foreach(println)
```